# Is it possible for jquery.each function not to clobber the 'this' variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So if the variable "this" is currently set to an object,

```
{ name: "The old this" }
```

the following code will change it in the loop

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
$.each(array,
  function(i, e){
    alert(this.name);
  }
);
```

this.name wont be found, instead the variable "this" is set to the same as 'e' during the loop execution

Is it possible to have jquery not clobber the this variable on $.each loops?

Comment: That's not possible. To be satisfied, you can store `this` in a temporary variable, say `that`, and refer to `that` instead of `this` inside `$.each`.

Comment: ok thanks. I might consider just using a regular for loop in that case then

Comment: For a simple loop, where non-complex variables are used, a normal loop is indeed the best choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the native `.forEach` instead of `$.each`, you can set the `this` value for the callback by sending a second argument...

```
array.forEach(function(e, i) {
    alert(this.name);
}, this);
```

You'll need to patch older browsers, including IE8...

- [Compatibility patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) from MDN

---

Or you can use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to return a function with the desired `this` value...

```
$.each(array, $.proxy(function(i, e) {
    alert(this.name);
}, this) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store `this` into a local variable and then use it inside `each` loop. Try this.

```
var data = this;//where this = { name: "The old this" }
var array = [1, 2, 3];
$.each(array,
  function(i, e){
    alert(data.name);
  }
);
```

Inside `each` loop `this` will point to each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, one more solution, using native JS and similar to `$.proxy`, is to use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
// wrapper function to set `this` scope.
(function() {

  $.each([1, 2, 3], (function(i, e) {
    alert(this.name);
  }).bind(this));

}).call({ name: "The old this" });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want `this` to be changed, then just use a normal `for` loop:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // operate on array[i]
    alert(this.name);
}
```

There is nothing you can do to change the behavior of jQuery's `.each()`.  It is coded to set `this`.  The `.each()` iterator is meant as a convenience - thus you should only use it when it is indeed more convenient than the `for` loop, not when it causes more trouble.

The other answers have shown you how you can save `this` to another variable.

Or, with ES6, you can declare your callback using an arrow function that will then ignore the `this` value that `jQuery.each()` tries to set and will keep the lexical value of `this`.