# How to use $.each() inside class/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, each

I'm rather beginning in JavaScript/jQuery, so pardon my question if it feels too basic.

I have class with two (or more) methods, one calls another inside it inside jQuery `$.each()` loop.

```
class X {
    method_a (array){
        $.each(array, function(index, item){
            this.method_b(item);
        });
    }
    method_b (item) {
        // do something with item
    }
}
```

But this throws TypeError, that method_b is not a function, since `this` refers to the `item` instead of **this object**. Is there any other way properly call `this` inside a jQuery $.each() or the only way is to make a variable `let obj = this;` and call it a day?

Am I missing something? Maybe something with methods' declaration?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an arrow function instead, `(index, item) => {`

Comment: Arrow function is a no-go for me as it does not work on IE :-( Damn IE...

Comment: Then use Babel to transpile your code down to ES5 automatically - don't let obsolete browsers cripple the readability of your code

Comment: oldschool way of doing it:

`class X {
    method_a (array){
        var that = this;
        $.each(array, function(index, item){
            that.method_b(item);
        });
    }
    method_b (item) {
        // do something with item
    }
}`

Comment: @Lumpenstein that was my first idea, but it looks terrible, so I'm trying to avoid it, hence asking this question ;-)

Comment: the newer way of doing it is to use the .bind/.call./apply functions to pass the 'this' context, but not sure if this is supported with jQuery (haven't used it for 2 years)

Comment: @Eric see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244018/is-it-possible-for-jquery-each-function-not-to-clobber-the-this-variable) for another way